# Karma Configuration using Resharper Unit Testing

Tags: jasmine, resharper, karma-runner

I am trying to setup JavaScript unit testing in our current project. We are using Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper. An optimal solution would be to use the ReSharper Test Runner since we are already using it for our backend tests. Now, I am wondering if there is an option to use a `karma.config.js` with ReSharper so that I see all of my JavaScript test in the Unit Test Session well and not in the built-in Test Explorer from VS. I have tried the [Karma Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd59e4a-82e8-4b4e-8302-d102fc81b090) and [Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah). However, both integrate with the Test Explorer and not the R# Unit Test Sessions. Chutzpah only provides an Extension that integrates into VS Unit Test Explorer as you can see [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe?SRC=VSIDE).

So is it possible to use a karma configuration with ReSharper to enable code coverage and more? Also using a bunch of `/// <reference path=".." />` tags does not seem ideal.